# ZF2 Database table no instance returned

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2

I am facing a problem with my database models in ZF2, I must have touch something in the application as I am sure it worked before.

Wondering if somebody can read out the problem by the follow error messages I've got.

If more error info is needed I can update this question with the stacks :)

```
 Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

 File:
 /home/xxxxx/domains/xxxx.nl/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:909

 Message:
 An exception was raised while creating "Application\Model\CelebrityTable"; no instance returned



 **Previous exceptions:**
 Zend\Db\TableGateway\Exception\RuntimeException

 File:
 /home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php:105

 Message:
 This table object does not have a valid table set.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the exceptions says most of what you need to know.

```
File:
 /home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php:105

 Message:
 This table object does not have a valid table set.
```

I went to `Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php:105` and the following piece of code is there;

```
if (!is_string($this->table) && !$this->table instanceof TableIdentifier && !is_array($this->table)) {
    throw new Exception\RuntimeException('This table object does not have a valid table set.');
}
```

So your exceptions means. The `$this->table` is not a `string`, `array` or an `instanceof Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier`

So you probably didn't set the table.

Now I never used the `AbstractTableGateway` so not sure how to use it in the right context. But I don't see a `setTable`, or something like a `setOptions`.

So unless you can show your implementation of your TableGateWay, this is as far as I know.

**Note, I looked at zf2.3.3**

Comment: PERFECT! yes, i made the mistake with my notation of writing $this->_table instead of $this->table .... Thank you so much